# "tab-pane active" output when using navbarmenu as a first item in navbarpage

Tags: shiny

If `navbarMenu` is the first item in `navbarPage`, I get a *“tab-pane active”* output in the browser. This is a known issue. I could not find a solution or work-around, if any, hence the post. Any help is appreciated.

Using shiny_0.11.1

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Regression", windowTitle = "Regression",
    navbarMenu("Data",
        tabPanel("Upload",
            fluidRow(
                column(12,
                       fileInput("csv_file", "Choose CSV Data File to Upload",
                                 accept = c("text/csv",
                                            "text/comma-separated-values",
                                            ".csv"))
                )
            ),
            tags$hr(),
            dataTableOutput("csv_data_table")
        ),
        tabPanel("Summary",
            fluidRow(
                column(4, offset = 4,
                       numericInput("datasummary_numobs_numeric",
                                    "No. of Obs.",
                                    value = NULL) #max = 6.0
                )
            ),
            tags$hr(),
            dataTableOutput("datasummary_data_table")
       )
    )
))
```